# Highlighting Issue

Tags: jquery, html, filtering

**I have an issue with my highlighting I can't seem to find the solution to.
I have a table & an input box.**

**When typing in the input box, the table is being sorted depending on what is in the input box. To clarify what is being searched for, I have highlighted all characters (in the table) that match the input value like in the following example:**

> input: Book in t
>
> Cell value: Today I am reading a **book in t**he garden.
>
> The purpose of this would be to clarify where the value matches with
>   your input.

This works great, but it has one issue. When removing the value from the input field, the last letter that was removed *always* remains highlighted. My question is if someone can spot my mistake. For some reason the html bold tags do not get removed when the input box is empty.

So, to give an example related to the previous:

> Last removed letter: B
>
> What all cells with the B look like:
>
> Today I am reading a **b**ook in the garden.
>
> Frank is **b**orrowing a book

I use the following JQuery & HTML code:

*HTML:*

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableRow">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="search" class="form-control tableFilter" placeholder="Filter..." /></td>
        <!--<td><input type="search" class="form-control tableFilter" placeholder="Filter..." /></td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Definition</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--Defintions-->
    @{
        foreach (UIDefinition definition in Model.DefinitionList)
        {
            <tr class="filterRow">
                <!--Automated Definitions-->
                @if (definition.Target != null)
                {
                    <td class="col-lg-4 hl filter">@Quick.LinkForLinkable(Html, definition.Target)</td>
                    <td class="col-lg-7 hl filter">@definition.Explanation</td>
                    <td class="col-lg-2">

                        <!--Edit-->
                        <a href="#edit-@definition.Id" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit editCustom-form" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-@definition.Id"></a>

                        <!--Dialog Window-->
                        <div id="edit-@definition.Id" class="modal fade modal-sm editCustom-form" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit definition</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="/Api/@Model.ApiName/@definition.Id" method="PATCH">
                                            <label class="col-lg-12">
                                                Name:
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" value="@definition.Term" disabled/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="col-lg-12">
                                                Definition:
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Explanation" placeholder="Definition" value="@definition.Explanation" />
                                            </label>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success modal-create addNew" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                }
```

*JQuery:*

```
//Table Filter based on input
    $(".tableFilter").keyup(function () {
        var rows = $(".table").find("tbody tr");
        //Filter the jquery object to get results.
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            //First hide all and remove class used to identify matched rows
            rows.removeClass("match").hide().filter(function () {
                var match = false;
                $(this).find("td.filter").each(function () {
                    var indexOf = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(".tableFilter").val().toLowerCase());
                    //Check with indexOf if this row cell include search string
                    if (indexOf !== -1) {
                        match = true;
                        return;
                    }
                });
                return match;
            }).addClass("match").show();
        } else {
            //If filter not provided show all 
            rows.removeClass("match").show().find("b").contents().unwrap
        }

    highlight(this.value);
});

var highlight = function (string) {
    $(".table").find("tbody tr.match td.filter").each(function () {

        if ($(this).text().indexOf(string) === -1)
            return;

        var matchStartIndex = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase());
        var matchEndIndex = matchStartIndex + string.length - 1;

        var beforeMatch = $(this).text().slice(0, matchStartIndex);
        var matchText = $(this).text().slice(matchStartIndex, matchEndIndex + 1);
        var afterMatch = $(this).text().slice(matchEndIndex + 1);

        //Here set selected text to e.g. bold style
        $(this).html(beforeMatch + "<b>" + matchText + "</b>" + afterMatch);
    });
};
```

Comment: Firstly, you shouldn't use `keyup` event but `input`: `$(".tableFilter").on('input', function () {...});`. Secondly, this does nothing: `rows.removeClass("match").show().find("b").contents().unwrap` you aren't calling `unwrap()`. Thirdly, i don't know if any of my previous points fix your issue but i guess the second one is your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't calling `$.fn.unwrap` here:

```
rows.removeClass("match").show().find("b").contents().unwrap
```

So fix it using:

```
rows.removeClass("match").show().find("b").contents().unwrap();
```

And consider to use `input` event that handle more cases as e.g cutting/pasting input's content using mouse.

```
$(".tableFilter").on('input', function () {...});
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I did not notice.
Would you be willing to try and answer a follow up question?
In my tables there are values that are clickable. These values have their own page and need to remain clickable during & after searching. Right now, when one of those values contains a match, the value within the cell loses its <a> tag and can no longer be clicked. When removing the search input, it still remains unclickable. Is there a way for the value to keep it's link tag?

Comment: Please consider to post a new question regarding your link issue

Comment: I have tried. Sadly I can only post a question every 90 minutes. Could you help me here?

Comment: I'll be offline in 15min, so if you post a jsfiddle before it with minimalistic sample replicating issue, i could have a look at it

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I couldn't get the jsfiddle to work. Maybe it has to do with me using asp.net mvc5 and the razor engine?

Comment: Copy/paste relevant HTML as it is generated client side (show source page in browser) and the relevant js too. But now i guess it would be too late for me to help but you could still post a new question later with the jsfiddle

Comment: I haven't got much experience with the fsfiddle and somehow could not get it to work.
Posted a new question just now! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809284/jquery-retain-link-tag-on-cell-filter-highlight