# Retain link tag on cell filter highlight

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have an issue with my highlighting I can't seem to find the solution to.
I have a table & an input box.**

**When typing in the input box, the table is being sorted depending on what is in the input box. To clarify what is being searched for, I have highlighted all characters (in the table) that match the input value like in the following example:**

> input: Book in t
>
> Cell value: Today I am reading a **book in t**he garden.
>
> The purpose of this would be to clarify where the value matches with
>   your input.

This works great, but it has an issue. Some values in the cells are clickable (so they are links with an  tag) and they redirect the user to the page that belongs to that cell value. When one of these clickable values have a match with the input value, they do highlight, but they also lose their link tag. I am wondering if it is possible for the link tag to be saved during and after searching.

I use the following JQuery & HTML code:

*HTML (Client Side):*

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr class="tableRow">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="search" class="form-control tableFilter" placeholder="Filter..."></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Definition</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--Defintions-->
            <tr class="filterRow">
                <!--Automated Definitions-->
                    <td class="col-lg-4 hl filter"><span>#</span></td>
                    <td class="col-lg-7 hl filter"><span>Appendix</span></td>
                    <td class="col-lg-1 "></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="filterRow">
                <!--Automated Definitions-->
                    <td class="col-lg-4 hl filter"><span>Arm's Length (Principle)</span></td>
                    <td class="col-lg-7 hl filter"><span>To do business 
                    between Related Companies under the same terms and 
                    conditions as unrelated 
                    companies would</span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col-lg-1 "></td>
           </tr>
```

*HTML:*

```
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr class="tableRow">
            <td colspan="2"><input type="search" class="form-control tableFilter" placeholder="Filter..." /></td>
        <!--<td><input type="search" class="form-control tableFilter" placeholder="Filter..." /></td>-->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Definition</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!--Defintions-->
    @{
        foreach (UIDefinition definition in Model.DefinitionList)
        {
            <tr class="filterRow">
                <!--Automated Definitions-->
                @if (definition.Target != null)
                {
                    <td class="col-lg-4 hl filter">@Quick.LinkForLinkable(Html, definition.Target)</td>
                    <td class="col-lg-7 hl filter">@definition.Explanation</td>
                    <td class="col-lg-2">

                        <!--Edit-->
                        <a href="#edit-@definition.Id" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit editCustom-form" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-@definition.Id"></a>

                        <!--Dialog Window-->
                        <div id="edit-@definition.Id" class="modal fade modal-sm editCustom-form" role="dialog">
                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                                        <h4 class="modal-title">Edit definition</h4>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">
                                        <form action="/Api/@Model.ApiName/@definition.Id" method="PATCH">
                                            <label class="col-lg-12">
                                                Name:
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" value="@definition.Term" disabled/>
                                            </label>
                                            <label class="col-lg-12">
                                                Definition:
                                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Explanation" placeholder="Definition" value="@definition.Explanation" />
                                            </label>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default modal-cancel" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success modal-create addNew" data-dismiss="modal">Confirm</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                }
```

*JQuery:*

```
//Table Filter based on input
    $(".tableFilter").keyup(function () {
        var rows = $(".table").find("tbody tr");
        //Filter the jquery object to get results.
        if (this.value.length > 0) {
            //First hide all and remove class used to identify matched rows
            rows.removeClass("match").hide().filter(function () {
                var match = false;
                $(this).find("td.filter").each(function () {
                    var indexOf = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf($(".tableFilter").val().toLowerCase());
                    //Check with indexOf if this row cell include search string
                    if (indexOf !== -1) {
                        match = true;
                        return;
                    }
                });
                return match;
            }).addClass("match").show();
        } else {
            //If filter not provided show all 
            rows.removeClass("match").show().find("b").contents().unwrap
        }

    highlight(this.value);
});

var highlight = function (string) {
    $(".table").find("tbody tr.match td.filter").each(function () {

        if ($(this).text().indexOf(string) === -1)
            return;

        var matchStartIndex = $(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(string.toLowerCase());
        var matchEndIndex = matchStartIndex + string.length - 1;

        var beforeMatch = $(this).text().slice(0, matchStartIndex);
        var matchText = $(this).text().slice(matchStartIndex, matchEndIndex + 1);
        var afterMatch = $(this).text().slice(matchEndIndex + 1);

        //Here set selected text to e.g. bold style
        $(this).html(beforeMatch + "<b>" + matchText + "</b>" + afterMatch);
    });
};
```

Comment: You should post the rendered HTML markup as it appears in browser, not the server side code. Here, we don't know what is e.g `@Quick.LinkForLinkable(Html, definition.Target)` etc... You could just copy/paste a sample using the code source of page in the browser

Comment: I have added the start of the table from the clientside HTML. It is only 2 rows, but it shows what the LinkForLinkable does. There are many more lines but they look the same with different data. I hope this allows you to help. If you need any more code, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet of code simulates what you're trying to achieve. When highlighted, the elements do not lose their 'redirecting' property:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<style>
.highlight { background-color:#FFFF00; }

td{
border: 1px solid red;
}

</style>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function highlightIt(t) {
    var inputText=$(t).val();
    for (i = 0; i < $('#theTable').find('tr').length; i++) { 
        var nthElement=$('#theTable').find('tr:eq('+i+')');
        for (j = 0; j < $(nthElement).find('td').length; j++) {
            var highlightedSpan=$(nthElement).find('p:eq('+j+') a span:eq(0)');
            var notHighlightedSpan=$(nthElement).find('p:eq('+j+') a span:eq(1)');
            var txtVal=$(notHighlightedSpan).text();

            if($(highlightedSpan).text().concat(txtVal).includes(inputText)){               
                $(notHighlightedSpan).text($(highlightedSpan).text().concat($(notHighlightedSpan).text()).replace(inputText, ''));
                $(highlightedSpan).text(inputText);
            }else{
                $(notHighlightedSpan).text($(highlightedSpan).text().concat($(notHighlightedSpan).text()));
                $(highlightedSpan).text('');
            } 
        } 
    }
}
</script>
<table id="theTable">
<tr>
    <td><p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.w3schools.com"><span class="highlight"></span><span>W3Schools</span></a></p></td>
    <td><p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://www.google.es"><span class="highlight"></span><span>Google</span></a></p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><p>An absolute URL: <a href="https://netbeans.org/"><span class="highlight"></span><span>NetBeans</span></a></p></td>
    <td><p>An absolute URL: <a href="http://www.eclipse.org"><span class="highlight"></span><span>Eclipse</span></a></p></td>
</tr>

</table>
Search:<input id="theInput" oninput="highlightIt(this)"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not very experienced in JQuerry and I am trying to understand your snippet. I cannot seem to be able to get this to work in JSFiddle or my code (when I replace the javascript). Could you advise me on how to proceed with this snippet?

Comment: I just tested it this way: 1)copy it in a .txt file 2) change the extension of the .txt to .html. 3) then double click it 4) your default browser will appear and show you the html content

Comment: Ah right, that works! It still only changes the background when it is a complete match. When I type: NetB, the NetBeans link wont highlight. Would it be possible to somehow combine the functionality of my and your functionality?

Comment: To achieve what you've asked you can't just work with css. It must be done via javascript. I edited the snippet so that a 'dynamic' highlightning is performed. Let me know if it works for you